# RavenDB build #2127 Client side exception: [Argument_StreamNotReadable] when trying to create a new Database

Tags: database, exception, iis, deployment, ravendb

I just downloaded the new unstable release of RavenDB #2127 according to [Ayende's announcement](https://twitter.com/ayende/status/259725519963185152).

I want to test how fast it'll perform on an existing app that's currently using build #888.

RavenDB is [deployed as an IIS application](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application).

`Web.config` had:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

I was getting a forbidden exception. Then I changed it to:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
```

Now I'm getting the following "awful" exception when trying to create a new Database using Raven Studio.

If you know what's causing this, please share the solution.

```
 at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Func`2 func)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.Execute.OnTheUI(Action action)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass30.<Catch>b__2e(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()



Client side exception:
System.ArgumentException: [Argument_StreamNotReadable]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.10411.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Argument_StreamNotReadable
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at Raven.Studio.Models.ApplicationModel.AddErrorNotification(Exception exception, String message, Object[] details)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass30.<>c__DisplayClass32.<Catch>b__2f()
   at AsyncCtpThreadingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<InvokeAsync>b__3()
```

I also opened a bug report at RavenDB issue tracking site. If you want to follow it, here's the link:

http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging with Ayende on a Skype chat, he just mentioned this:

> [10/21/12 3:10:31 AM] Oren Eini: When running in IIS... did you enable
>   Windows Auth? You need it to create a new DB.

It turns out that Windows authentication was not even installed on my machine... I'm trying this in a new Windows 8 install. So I had to go and [install the Windows auth feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2007/08/20/how-do-i-turn-on-windows-authentication-in-iis-7.aspx). Then I went to IIS and enabled Windows Auth for the RavenDB Website:

[image]

Now creating a new database through Raven Studio JUST WORKS! :)

Ayende is always present helping us get the most out of RavenDB. Excellent support from his part.